# What is the average reduction in air pressure for a mountain bike tire?

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, tire-pressure

I've noticed that my mountain bike tire looses air, not because of a leak, etc., but just naturally as time progresses.

Does anybody know the average psi loss over time for a mountain bike tire and tube?

Just the average for a 29" wheel.

Comment: Depends on the tube, and, of course, on the pressure.  With my road bike I figure to pump up my tires every 3-5 days (depending on how fussy I'm being).  But some road tubes leak down substantially in 24 hours.  Mtn bike tires should last a bit longer, because they're lower pressure and larger volume.

Comment: It would be nice if a tire or tube manufacturer provided some technical info. online about average psi reduction for a healthy tire.  Would keep the guess work out of a slow leak vs. natural loss.

Comment: Too highly variable, plus the fast leakers don't want to admit it.

Comment: Varies quite a bit - not sure why but sometimes I am surprise how soft the tires have gone in a short time, other times (same bike, same wheels, same tires, same tubes) they seem to last months and are till good to ride.  With a family I have 5 bikes to maintain, sometimes it feels seems I spend more timeadding air tires than riding..... If you are worried, change tubes to a different brand - stay away from light weight ones.

Comment: Generally the higher the pressure and the smaller the volume of the inner tube, the faster the pressure loss. The quality of the valve plays a part and a Schrader valve being more prone to loss than a Presta valve that is screwed tight.

Comment: If your MTB uses Schrader (car-type) valves check and maybe replace the core with a motorbike type core, they have stronger closing springs as they are designed to counteract centrifugal forces. There are special and cheap tools to replace cores.

Comment: @Carel - The Presta valve should not be screwed TOO tight.  Just to where the fingers feel some resistance.  If you over-tighten you deform the gasket and it's more likely to leak eventually.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, that's for sure, by tight I meant fingertight!

Comment: I'm riding 29 tires and can't say I've noticed any pressure drop in 6 weeks. Checked them a couple of days ago and still had 50psi in the back and 45psi in the front. I do use it 4 times a week though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continental tire ( they make tubes as well ) states that their tubes loose about 5 psi per week and suggests topping them off on a weekly basis.

This information is not published but they will tell you as much on their support line if you speak German.

For a tube and tire combination, the tube is designed to hold the air in, not the tire and is the point of loss to consider.